# Convenient tool to insert data into SQLite database?

Tags: android, sqlite

Can anyone please suggest me a tool (preferably freeware) to insert data into a SQLite database? Most tools I've found allow you to only run queries, not insert.

The reason I need this, is because tables in he database contain BLOB fields, and I need to pre-feed data before deploying my application. And it's not really cool to do this in code.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question - the most feature-rich tool I was able to find is [SQLite2009 Pro Enterprise Manager](http://osenxpsuite.net/?xp=3). And it's free which is really important to me.

Answer (score 0):

I use a pretty convenient and open source tool called "Mike T's SQL Database App". It lets you open an SQLite database, perform manual SQL queries as well as use a GUI to insert/edit/remove data all with minimal hassle.

There are Linux, Windows and Mac OS X versions available although he has currently stopped updating the tool, to be honest through my uses I don't think I've ever come across a bug.

[Mike T's SQL Database App](http://saxmike.com/MySoftware/MySoftware.asp?Menu=MYSOFTWARE)

Comment: Well, Mike T's tool is indeed pretty simple and convinient, but it doesn't provide any functionality to store a BLOB from a binary file. For example, it would be really helpful to be able to just select an image and let the tool insert bytes into the field